# How do you get the directory Security tab in XP Home or XP Media Center Edition?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions

I work with XP Professional everywhere, and never needed the ability to change directory permissions on my home machine.  Lately, I've been running into a [massive headache with IIS and ASP.NET permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268871/can-you-run-an-asp-net-mvc-application-from-its-project-folder).

Is there an easy way to get access to the "Security" tab that is found in XP Professional on XP Home, or possibly a better tool to deal with this?

Comment: Related, in not duplicate: [Enable Security tab in Explorer folder properties for windows XP home edition](http://superuser.com/q/130197/228536)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security settings for XP Media Center Edition should be the same as pro as it is built on top of it. Go to any folder (or open Windows Explorer) then go to tools > folder options and under view, the last option should be "Use simple folder sharing (Recommended)". When this is disabled, you will get the security tab.

As for Windows XP Home, you shouldn't be having problems with IIS as it should not be running! However, I believe that the security tab is disabled in home edition, however you will most likely still be able to edit folder permissions by using [XCACLS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754) or a third party tool. I cannot really help further on home as - well - I have never used it :S

Comment: Good information, I had no idea IIS 5.1 wasn't included with Home Edition or that Media Center Edition was built on XP Pro. I'll be upgrading to Windows 7 as soon as I can

Comment: In XP home you need to boot into safe mode to get the security tab to show up.

Answer (score 1):

From here: http://www.lockergnome.com/windows/2005/03/07/displaying-the-security-tab-in-xp-home-edition/

> Displaying the security tab in XP Pro
>   can be achieved by disabling simple
>   file sharing. You can accomplish this
>   by opening the Folder Options applet
>   in the Control Panel. Click the View
>   tab and remove the check beside the
>   Use simple file sharing (recommended)
>   option.

I have Media Center Edition and this method worked.