# Enable Security tab in Explorer folder properties for windows XP home edition

Tags: windows-xp

I want to enable (display) the Security tab for file/folder properties in Windows XP home editon.  I've already seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/109183/how-to-enable-the-security-tab-in-explorer-folder-properties) but do not seem to have the 'Use Simple File Sharing' option available to uncheck.
I've also double-checked and the file system is NTFS formatted.

Is this just a limitation of XP home edition, or is there something I can install/hack to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/tips/xp_home_sectab.htm) details one way (which does appear to be the only way)

Basically you download and install the [Security Configuration Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/ntserver/nts/downloads/recommended/scm/default.asp)

Comment: I was writing the same thing while you posted. 1 speedpoint for you thou ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. The first link appears to be broken though.
I googled scesp4i.exe and found this page (http://www.misec.net/forum/board/FAQ/1144075199) which has some useful instructions.

Answer (score 3):

According to (http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/49800-security-tab-acls-in-xp-home-yeah/) there are two more ways to do this thing, without having to download something Windows XP Home does natively (although only in Safe Mode).
Quoting the user's (KJxp) answer:

> 1. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Option` and set a DWORD value named `OptionValue` to `1`. This takes effect immediately. However, if you restart with this value still in, Windows will function, but it won't load Visual Styles and other normal-mode-only things. It's best to just use a `.reg` file to set it to `1` when you want the tab functionality.
> 2. Easier yet is a patch: http://www.rt-sw.de/en/freeware/freeware.html It changes ONE BYTE in `rshx32.dll` (a backslash to a space at `0x9F0`), saves it under a new `.dll` name, and registers it (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{1F2E5C40-9550-11CE-99D2-00AA006E086C}\InProcServer32`). This also takes effect immediately, and works perfectly in SP2!

The first solution should "enable" the Safe Mode functions. Since display drivers are already loaded, it would only convert the system in Safe Mode after the next restart.
The second solution has a dead link, but the user explains the process, so it should be easy to replicate with a hex editor.

Since these solutions are somewhat obscured by the `scesp4i.exe` solution, I thought this would be a good place to divulge them. After all, why install something if the OS does it right off the box?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, and thank you for the clear and well written answer you've provided. :D