# Is auditing possible on Windows XP Home Edition?

Tags: windows-xp, security, group-policy

Although Windows XP Professional has (a lot more) control over Security issues, Windows XP Home Edition does allow the regular user to probe around and allows to set Security settings on folders and files. Usually this is done using Safe Mode although some [other shortcuts](https://superuser.com/a/602854/228536) do exist.

Now, on the Settings tab there exists the possibility of auditing a directory and its' files. From what I understood, it allows to register any and all changes to the structure and the files contained on to the Event Log.

I've proceeded to test this, using a test folder and a test file (and the solution I pointed in the link). However, no thing appears to be registered in the event log.

I believe one has to allow in the Local Security Policy the possibility to audit individual folders, as explained [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/step-by-step-how-to-audit-file-and-folder-access-to-improve-windows-2000-pro-security/).

However, and as you might have figured it out, Home Edition doesn't have Group Policy. I was looking for some way to alter those values without resorting to the Group Policy but I found out Audit Settings aren't stored in the registry ([source](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/F/B/8FBD2E85-8852-45EC-8465-92756EBD9365/WindowsVistaGroupPolicySettings.xls)).

I'm somewhat apprehensive in using SCM (as detailed in my first link) because it was a tool made for Windows 2000 and not for XP.

This being said, I ask whether there is a way to access the Audit Settings, alter them, and finally audit a folder, in Windows XP Home Edition.

Comment: You are aware that Windows XP supports end in 2014 right?

Comment: I am. We're in 2013.

Comment: Just upgrade to Windows XP Pro instead of trying to hack in something that was intentionally removed -- You'd be done by now. ;)

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - While it is indeed still 2013 the fact you are spending time to setup Auditing on Windows XP in 2013 is concerning.  Trying to be a good internet neighbor and offer my help to dismantle your busted trash cans.

Comment: @Ramhound (Un)fortunately that trash can is my *main* computer (and it isn't busted, yet). Yes I've had it for a long time. Yes it is most likely a piece of junk. And Yes, I shouldn't spend this amount of time trying to figure out something like this. I'm trying to, however, because Windows (in general) has this and it seemed more direct than using other pieces of software. FWIW I'm not interested in full-scale Auditing, just wanted to know if *someone somewhere* solved this and if it did, how. It would be useful for some projects I have.

Comment: I don't accept the use of Windows XP is required.  VMWare, Virtual PC, Hyber-V, Virtualbox can all solve any applications that don't support Windows 7+  People interested in Auditing are unlikely to purchase Home Edition, so a solution is unlikely to exist, because the lack of a  group policy manager.

Comment: @Ramhound the sensibility of one's goals does not inherently invalidate a question. Although it may seem silly to be trying to do this on Windows XP Home in 2013, not everybody can afford (or maybe even has the desire) to upgrade their software frequently, let alone purchase the hardware required to run a newer OS. Let's focus on _answering_ the question rather than criticizing its purpose.

Comment: @Ramhound, It's actually almost 2015 now. Windows XP still lives.

Comment: @Pacerier - Why would you comment on something I said a year and half ago?

Comment: @Ramhound, To indicate that it's  almost 2015 now yet Windows XP still lives.